How to mix `autoCommit=true` and `autoCommit=true` @Transactional operations in a single Spring Boot application for one DataSource?
I wish Spring @Transactional would add support for autoCommit=true, similar to the readOnly=true option. In my Spring Boot application, I would like to use a mix of:

autoCommit=false (default) semantics for all @Transactional methods, except one.
autoCommit=true (new) semantics for one @Transactional method.

I think Spring supports autoCommit=true at the DataSource level only, not in the @Transactional annotation?

Long term => Please add @Transactional support for autoCommit=true, similar to readOnly=true. I think both make sense for a lot of use cases, but only the latter is supported at the moment.
Short term => Please let me know how to mix autoCommit=false and autoCommit=true semantics in a Spring Boot application? I tried, but could not get it working.

Sample code is provided at the end. My failed workaround attempt details are also at the end.

Use case: Run a REST client to do 10/sec successful user authentications against a Spring Boot REST API. Then try to scale it up to 100/sec and 1000/sec.
Problem: Authentication provider synchronously invokes ApplicationEventListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>, which calls a @Service to update two fields in a JPA User entity (i.e. locked, last_login_date), plus a @Version field.
I identified these bottlenecks in my high-concurrency scalability testing:

Spring-side autoCommit=false housekeeping => latency due to DB housekeeping calls (i.e. SET AUTOCOMMIT=0, BEGIN, COMMIT, SET AUTOCOMMIT=1)
Spring-side retries => update @Version retries, due to @Retryable semantics in READ COMMITTED mode
PostgreSQL-side WAL => Using findById and save generated UPDATE statements for all columns

I addressed 3 by using a @Modifying @Query in my JpaRepository; see example code.
I would like to use autoCommit=true semantics to address 1. I think that would indirectly mitigate 2 as well.

user table columns:

id, username, password, email_address, home_address, etc => not updated by listener
locked, last_login_date, version => updated by listener


My understanding of @Transactional is it roughly translates my @Service method to five SQL client calls to the DB:

SET AUTOCOMMIT=0
BEGIN
UPDATE user SET locked=false,last_login_date=NOW(),version=version+1 WHERE id=? AND version=?
END
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1

The four housekeeping calls 1-2 and 4-5 are wasteful.

If step 3 was a SELECT, readOnly=true would eliminate steps 1-2 and 4-5.
Since step 3 is an UPDATE, autoCommit=true could eliminate steps 1-2 and 4-5.


Sample code
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication instanceof MyAuthenticationSuccessEvent customEvent) {
            userService().updateSuccessfulAuthentication(customEvent.getUserId();
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Transactional
    @Retryable(value = {OptimisticLockingFailureException.class}, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 50))
    public void updateSuccessfulAuthentication(long userId) {
        userRepository.updateSuccessfulAuthentication(userId);
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.locked = false, u.lastLoginDate = NOW() WHERE u.id = :userId")
    void updateSuccessfulAuthentication(Long userId);
}


I attempted this workaround, but it didn't work

Create AutoCommitTransactionManager, a copy of DataSourceTransactionManager with autoCommit=false housekeeping code commented out.
Create AutoCommitTransactionManagerConfig, a copy of DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration declaring the DataSourceTransactionManager bean (with conditions removed), plus adding a new AutoCommitTransactionManager bean. Both TransactionManagers reference the same DataSource bean (i.e. my PostgreSQL DB instance).
Change @Service method to use @Transactional("autoCommitTransactionManager").

I could not get the above to work. The beans seemed to step on each other, or interfere with each other.
I don't know if this was a valid approach or not. If I missed something, please let me know and I will try it. Thank you.

Summary:
In the long term, I wish Spring will all an autoCommit=true option to @Transactional. There are other approaches, but adding an autoCommit=true would be ideal. It is a valid approach in other frameworks, it would not require any boilerplate code, and it would not require any refactoring to address the bottleneck in other ways.
In the short term, I wish I could get the two TransactionManager bean approach to work.


you are chasing the wrong goal: autocommit is an antonym of transaction, AutoCommitTransactionManager may exist in kind of weird universe only, I believe.

I am not sure that makes sense to me.
Auto-commit is just a mechanism of controlling the end of a transaction. A transaction means ACID, so Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, and Durability. If autoCommit=true, the client explicitly calls STATEMENT, and the DB implicitly does BEGIN, STATEMENT, COMMIT. If autoCommit=false, the client explicitly calls BEGIN, STATEMENT, COMMIT. Both are transactions.

the main problem is your homebrewed "information security" subsystem is broken by design: you are expecting to reach zillions rps whilst competing for the hot data in DB, that is not possible to achieve without extra tradeoffs. At first, you need to realise that the millisecond(s) difference in lastLoginDate does not make sense, moreover, I do believe, seconds do not make sense either, after that, you may come into conclusion that you can process authentication events asynchronously, moreover, you may keep them for a while and just periodically flush the final result.

Thank you for your responses, but they don't answer my question. The question I would like answered is the title and first section: How to mix autoCommit=true and autoCommit=true @Transactional operations in a single Spring Boot application for one DataSource? User update is just an example. I can change the example, or you can pick a better example, and the question can still apply. If you don't know an answer, it is OK. I am hoping someone can provide an answer to it. Thank you.

the answer you have gotten in the first comment is: "nohow. period". The entire JDBC API in Java is based on the presumption that autocommit is switched off (btw, readonly transactions in spring are broken by design as well), any attempt to screw up with that presumption is doomed to failure.

auto-commit with a transaction doesn't make sense. You can already eliminate parts of the things that worry you, disable auto commit on the datasource (that would eliminate 1 and 5), a transaction will always be there anyway (with or without an actual @Transactional the DB always has a tx, better be in control). You are also using JPA then set the property that the auto-commit is already managed (which should be set already if using an up-to-date version of Spring Boot) add spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true as a property.

These answers are not helpful. A simple example proves you wrong. Execute "SET AUTOCOMMIT=1; UPDATE table SET column=column+1;" on a table with 1 million rows, and that update happens atomically or not at all. Auto-commit is a convenience setting, not a requirement. You are incorrectly saying autoCommit=true is a requirement for a transaction, it is not, it is a convenience setting, and autoCommit=true absolutely does apply to transactions.

Auto-commit true doesn't apply to transactions, it basically tells the database to run every statement you fire at it in a separate transaction. So if you fire 2 update statements you have 2 implicit transactions. That is what auto-commit is. Hence auto-commit - trye wrapped in a transaction doesn't make sense because there is already a transaction on the db side (so you better control it)_. The heavy operation it enable/disable the autocommit not the start/end of the transaction.

Using autoCommit with an @Transactional doesn't make sense and beats the purpose of @Transactional. If you want that don't use @Transactional and you will have what you think you need (which it isn't).
When using autoCommit you basically loose control of the transaction and leave it to the database connection and/or the implicit transaction on the database side of things.
The fact that SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 is being set means you also have your DataSource set to autoCommit is true. Set that to false to disable autoCommit and you will get rid of the SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 / SET AUTOCOMMIT=1 calls. If you are on an up to date version of Spring Boot this will also automatically set the hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit to improve Hibernate on this as well. If not you will need to add spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true to your application.properties. (See this blog for more info on this as well).
That way you will get rid of the quite impact full setting of auto commit mode on transactions.
FOr the begin/end of a transaction there is not much you can or should do. There will always be a transaction on the DB side of things, so you better are in control of things.

Using autoCommit with a transaction absolutely does make sense. A transaction has a BEGIN and COMMIT. Auto-commit is nothing more than a convenience feature. It can be on or off, and a transaction will still take place. For example, if I execute "SET AUTOCOMMIT=1; UPDATE table SET column=column+1;" on a table with 1 million rows, that update is applied atomically. The fact I am using autoCommit is a convenience so I don't have to execute BEGIN and COMMIT myself, I am telling the database to do the transaction BEGIN and COMMIT steps automatically.

Auto commit with a transaction doesn't make sense. If you are executing multiple statements you don't want auto commit, that will only lead to trouble. There is also always a transaction either explicit (with a begin/end) or implicit on the database side, regardless there is a transaction. But as stated in the question if you set it to false and configure hibernate accordingly those auto-commit calls won't appear.
